# Como criar layout parecido com APP relógio

Tags: android, android-layout

Bom dia a todos. 
Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda em como criar um layout parecido com o APP relógio do Android? Gostaria de fazer algo bem parecido com essas telas. Se puderem me ajudar com código XML ou links de blogs e sites estarei grato. Gostaria principalmente desse efeito de lista com vários itens que podem ser expandidos, mas acredito que isso não seja expandable list view.

Parece que é uma lista com vários itens. Você clica para expandir o item, ele não tem outros subitens e sim o mesmo, só que aparecem mais informações.

[image: Uma lista de itens que são expandidos]
[image: Item da lista expandido.]

Answer (score 1):

Pra fazer isso, você pode sim usar um list view mas vai precisar fazer um custom adapter pra popular esse list view com um layout personalizado feito por você mesmo.  Já as abas desse aplicativo de relógio acredito que sejam feitas com material design, com um toolbar e ocultando a action bar.  Provavelmente usam um `fragmentStatePagerAdapter` e cada aba desse aplicativo,  é, obviamente um fragment. Você vai ter um pouco de trabalho pra conseguir fazer isso.  Mas nada que seja impossível.
Para fazer o efeito de expandir e mostrar os conteúdos adicionais,  você tem que fazer um layout interno,  dentro do que você usar no seu custom adapter que quando você clicar no ícone para expandir você seta esse layout como visível com:

```
layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

E quando o usuário clicar para diminuir as informações, você faz:

```
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Alguns links:

[Para ter uma ideia de Custom Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

[Para fazer abas com material designs](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

Comment: Minha dúvida principal e fazer essa expansão no adapter. O resto eu nem quero fazer. ListView com custom adapter eu sei fazer. Vou tentar implementar aqui e retorno. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ok, isso você consegue fazer setando a visibilidade mesmo. Boa sorte!

Comment: Consegui fazer com SetVisibility e animateLayoutChanges. Um pouco diferente mas o efeito em si desejado eu consegui. Obrigado.